# make a javascript HMAC token

Tags: javascript, encryption, encoding, cryptography, hmac

I am trying to emulate the following .NET code in javascript using the Crypto.js library.

```
var hashInput = "public=ID1000000001::routetype=POST::route=personsearch::key1=ID1000000001::key2=1043"
byte[] inputBytes = new byte[hashInput.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(hashInput.ToCharArray(), 0, inputBytes,0,inputBytes.Length);

byte[] keyBytes = HexadecimalStringToByteArray("A_HEX_STRING_GOES_HERE");

var hmac = HMACSHA256.Create();
hmac.Key = keyBytes;
var clientHash = hmac.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
```

This gives me a ByteArray which is used as part of POST to a WebAPI in the form of
[41,197,254,91,244,87.....] etc.

I want to make the same exact byte array in a javascript client but i am having diffculty getting this. I have tried the following:

```
var stringToHash = 'public=ID1000000001::routetype=POST::route=personsearch::key1=ID1000000001::key2=1043';
var privateKey = 'A_HEX_STRING_GOES_HERE';
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToHash, privateKey);
//this results in a WordArray, which can be converted to many types
//however i cannot get the byte array as in the .net example
//i.e. i just want to get [41,197,254,91,244,87....] etc.
```

I can see on the documentation for Crypto.js how to convert to base64, and other formats, but not to the ByteArray which i need.

Any ideas?

--UPDATE 
Thanks for the advice on not using BlockCopy, and also for pointing me in the direction of the encoding issues which i had completely neglected.

This was part of the issue. The other part was that i had managed to misuse the HMACSHA256 class. I found (after several, several hours) that the .NET code was not producing the correct hash value.

It turns out this code DID produce the correct Hash:

```
        var hashInput = "a::string::to::hash";
        var privateKey = "C0B615950F9D577A4EAF64C9B4F2E50F3DA2C6BB6F790FA346E9732788B29A08AC5444F1B82984DB190A75D3861CC4802D598EBF0025FD1C327928F43EB1C80E";    

        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashInput);
        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey);

        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
        hmac.Initialize();
        var clientHash = hmac.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(clientHash);
```

Lucky for me my WebAPI is not live yet!

Comment: +1 for well defining your question, kinda refreshing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably the character encoding. You should use for instance the method `encode_utf8(stringValue)` in JavaScript and `new UTF8Encoding.getBytes(String value)` in .NET, to make sure that the character encodings match. Note that modern cryptography is based on bytes, not on strings or characters. Using `System.Buffer.BlockCopy()` to encode characters is really bad practice.