# compute hmac from message bytes and key bytes in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, hmac, sha

I'm trying to reproduce the following code in javascript

```
var hashInput = "a::string::to::hash";
        var privateKey = "C0B615950F9D577A4EAF64C9B4F2E50F3DA2C6BB6F790FA346E9732788B29A08AC5444F1B82984DB190A75D3861CC4802D598EBF0025FD1C327928F43EB1C80E";    

        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashInput);
        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey);

        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
        hmac.Initialize();
        var clientHash = hmac.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(clientHash);
```

But i ignore how can i import Enocde and HMACSHA256. I found the code in the following answer:
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098658/make-a-javascript-hmac-token)

This is what i've tried so far

```
  const HashMAC = (key, message) => {
    let keyBytes = Buffer.from(key, 'base64');
    let messageBytes = Buffer.from(message, 'utf8');
    // i don't know which library should i use, in crypto js thay're talking about 
      message and key noy bytes i tried but nothing.
    const base64 = Buffer.from(hmac, 'base64');
    return base64;
  };
```

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code so far.

Comment: Please read [the HMAC documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/crypto.html#class-hmac) on the Node.js website.

Comment: I already read it, that's why i'm asking for help :)

Comment: In the linked code of your question CryptoJS is used, the newly added code and your last comment imply the crypto module of NodeJS. Please clarify which of the libraries should be used.

Comment: I mean, I tried both but i need to do in cryptoJS

Comment: You just need to pass your values in [`CryptoJS.HmacSHA256()`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#hmac): see online https://jsfiddle.net/4esa5c6w/. That's all. This gives the same result as the C# code: `N2QC/8VlfPQzaGge9AGAPVBijtph3YXttQh6sOyeu9U=`, see online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LvqxUf

Comment: _reactNativeCryptoJs.default.HmacSHA256 is not a function

Comment: Obviously environment specific. Possibly [this](https://github.com/imchintan/react-native-crypto-js/issues/8) issue. You've to find a library that is supported in your react-native environment.